# SharePoint Rest API for search functionality on list level

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I was wondering is there any rest api endpoint available to utilize the search functionality directly in a list level?

SharePoint is proviiding an option to search/find an item in list view. But is it possible through rest api?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use search API for that

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Path:https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Lists/listName%27
```

specify the list URL in the Path
.
You can use many other filters in search API. Please refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview